# How can I use function with 2 arguments includes 'self' in Python?

Tags: python, function, arguments

To solve the closed question, I post full code here.

```
import os
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import * 
from PyQt5 import uic

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
form_class = uic.loadUiType(BASE_DIR + "./test.ui")[0]

class WindowClass(QMainWindow, form_class):
    def __init__(self) :
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.func)

    def func(self, a):
        global b
        b = a

    
if __name__ == "__main__" :
    app = QApplication(sys.argv) 
    myWindow = WindowClass() 
    myWindow.show()
    app.exec_()
```

and also it needs ui file in same directory,

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>298</width>
    <height>197</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="maximumSize">
   <size>
    <width>298</width>
    <height>197</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="button">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>100</x>
      <y>80</y>
      <width>75</width>
      <height>23</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>PushButton</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

In this code,

```
class WindowClass(QMainWindow, form_class):
    def __init__(self) :
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.func(1))
    
    def func(self, a):
        global b
        b = a
```

This results in an argument error(**TypeError: argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'**). Is there any way to use the function `func`?

I tried `wc = WindowClass()` and changed code into:

```
class WindowClass(QMainWindow, form_class):
    def __init__(self) :
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        wc = WindowClass()
        self.button.clicked.connect(wc.func(1))
    
    def func(self, a):
        global b
        b = a
```

This results in a fatal initializing error(**Fatal Python error: _Py_CheckRecursiveCall: Cannot recover from stack overflow.
Python runtime state: initialized
Current thread 0x000097e8 (most recent call first):**).

The code works perfect when it is:

```
class WindowClass(QMainWindow, form_class):
    def __init__(self) :
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.func)
    
    def func(self):
        global b
        b = 1
```

However, I have to use `func` as 2 arguments. How can I do this?

Comment: Always include the complete error tracebacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using partial:

```
from functools import partial

self.button.clicked.connect(partial(self.func, 1))
```

My guess is that connect expects a 0 argument function. Partial fixates the argument and creates a 0 argument function.

Comment: Thanks for your help! It worked properly!